# Why am I receiving a tkinter.TclError when trying to get the content of a text widget?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-text

I'm trying to get the input from a tkinter text widget, but it is coming up with the error:

`_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!text"`

Here is where I define the textbox: `textbox = tkinter.Text(main_root)`

And this is how I call the get() function: `textbox.get("1.0", "end-1c")`

Anyone got any ideas what is going on? Usually this works fine.

Comment: You are probably calling `.get()` after the widget has been destroyed.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: error suggest that you want to get data from widget (or from window) which was destroyed. You have to get it before you destroy/close window.

Comment: Thank you both for helping out! I have managed to fix my problem. I will leave an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was calling `textbox.destroy()` before calling the get() function. This is what caused the error to be raised.